# Stop a thread ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor after some condition occure

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I want to have some thread pool, that runs some tasks every fixed amount of time (this thread pool keeps getting tasks all the time). Each task calls some API to get some value, which can be null. I want the task to run again (after fixed time) only if the returned value is null. Otherwise, I don't want this task to ever run again. Is there any way to achieve that? 
The only thing I had in mind is to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and kill the specific thread from within, but I didn't find a way to do that and I am not sure it's a good practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule tasks by one and check your condition before scheduling next task:

```java
public class Solver {

    final long delay = 500L;

    String getSomeValue() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.8) return "not-null";
        return null;
    }

    void init() {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(8);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String value = getSomeValue();
                System.out.println("" + value + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                if (value == null) {
                    executor.schedule(this, delay - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            }
        };
        executor.schedule(runnable, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solver().init();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like what I wanted. Correct me if I'm wrong, should it be 'if (value == null)' right? In addition, can you please explain this line - 'executor.schedule(this, delay - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);'? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it should be `value==null`. We use `delay - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)` to keep a fixed delay even if `getSomeValue` runs slow. If we just used `delay`, then if `getSomeValue` runs, for example, 25ms, then it will be invoked once per `delay + 25` ms, not once per `delay` ms.

Comment: Good Answer. But I would add a mention of the importance of properly shutting down an executor service when done using it. Otherwise its backing pool of threads may run indefinitely, like zombies ‍♂️